# optimize js script and find the best solution

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

i need to optimize this script by any way, may be you can find better algorithm for this sorting. this script get points like "Oslo - Tokyo, Moscow - Berlin, Rome - Barselona, Barselona - Oslo, Tokyo - Moscow, Berlin - New-York" and sort it. you can see it in this page http://at-no.ru/sorting.html - first is place of department, second is place of arrival, third and four does not matter. first button is "Add card" and second is "Sort cards". you can fill it in english. travel can't finish at the start point - in that case script will be looping and freezes.

```
function sortCards(arr) {   // card's sorting

        var map = {};   // create map
        for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            map[arr[i].from] = arr[i];  // fill map for each card

         }  

        for (var from in map) {     
            map[from].next = map[map[from].to];  // create linked list

         }

        for (var from in map) {
            for (var next = map[from]; next; next = next.next) {
                delete map[next.to]; // find start point

             }

            var start = from; // put from to var start
         }


        var arr = [];
        for (var point = map[start]; point; point = point.next) {

            arr.push(point);    // fill array

         }


        for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {

        var result = document.createElement("div");
        document.getElementById('entered').appendChild(result).innerHTML='<center>' + 'Get ' + arr[i].transport 
 + ' from ' + arr[i].from + ' to ' + arr[i].to + '. Place ' + arr[i].seat + '<br>' + '</center>';   // display the result

            }

        }
```

Comment: This does not seem like a question. Instead, it seems like a job. How much are you paying? ;)

Comment: i'am just asking for a hint, not for full solution. and well, if u give me cool solutiuon i can pay if you real need it)